# Access Registry From WebJob/WebApp

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have been trying, without success, to disable the RC4 Cipher on Azure.  I came across a code sample that worked with a Web Role:

```
string[] subKeys = new string[]
{
    "RC4 40/128",
    "RC4 56/128",
    "RC4 64/128",
    "RC4 128/128",
};

RegistryKey parentKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers", true);

foreach(string keyName in subKeys)
{
    var newKey = parentKey.CreateSubKey(keyName);
    newKey.SetValue("Enabled", 0);
    newKey.Close();
}
```

As we are using WebApp's, I created a WebJob containing the code above.  When executed I get a security exception:

System.Security.SecurityException: Requested registry access is not allowed.

Is there a way to run a WebJob in an elevated execution context?  Or a way to use PowerShell?

We are currently being audited and this was flagged as something which requires attention.

Comment: [Have you tried using startup scripts instead?](https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/19/how-to-disable-ssl-3-0-in-azure-websites-roles-and-virtual-machines/)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Startup scripts are for cloud services (web/worker roles).  Web Apps do not have startup scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with a WebApp. Because WebApps run in a multi-tenanted environment access to the registry is restricted. This page contains a feature comparison between WebApps and WebRoles.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/

Answer (score 1):

Like Alex said, you can't disable the RC4 Cipher yourself on an Azure Web App. However, in a few weeks Azure will be disabling various weak cipher suites across all sites, so you'll get it for free.

Their public announcement:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/50f1ab33-c22a-4629-951e-b7510f6b2cbe/upgrading-tlsssl-cryptography-for-azure-web-apps?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Thanks for the info - I was expecting to have to move to a Cloud Service to enable the configuration, but I'm happy to wait for the update in the link.

Comment: For those looking for this later, you need to pay 3x the price for Premium WebApps to do this. Standard, where you have your own dedicated instances, doesn't allow it for some bizarre reason.